# Retrieving Linked Profile via API or other means

Tags: linkedin-api, profile

I am looking to retrieve profiles of a handful of users via an API or programmatically. I could do this manually which would take me a few hours or can download HTML or connect via an API. What is possible with linked in services and what would you recommend? Is there an API I can subscribe to for this? #linkedin

I tried to manually note down details of a linked in profile one by one but it seems quite inefficient to do that - I simply need to do this for a handful of profiles.